# qualified names in C++ class declaration

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, msvc12

According to [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class), the class name can be "optionally qualified". Thus, I expect the following code to compile:

```
struct ::globalSt {};
```

In MSVC 2013u4, I get an error:

> Error 1   error C2039: 'globalSt' : is not a member of '`global namespace''

Am I misinterpreting the reference or is that a MSVC bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define a class with a qualified name, the name must have been previously declared. [class]/11

> If a *class-head-name* contains a *nested-name-specifier*, the *class-specifier* shall refer to a class that was
>   previously declared directly in the class or namespace to which the *nested-name-specifier* refers, or in an
>   element of the inline namespace set (7.3.1) of that namespace (i.e., not merely inherited or introduced by
>   a *using-declaration*), and the *class-specifier* shall appear in a namespace enclosing the previous declaration.
>   In such cases, the *nested-name-specifier* of the *class-head-name* of the definition shall not begin with a
>   *decltype-specifier*.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work the class must be already delcared. If you put a `struct globalst;` somewhere in your code before your definition it will work fine.

For example if you do

```
struct MyStruct;
```

then do

```
struct ::MyStruct {};
```

it should compile.

Tested with MSVC 2013.